# How to provide a static link to a Google Doc that is unique to each user

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api

This doesn't feel like a unique problem, but I can't find an existing solution.

Background:
I am building a course in an LMS.  I can insert links, but they are static links and each user will see the same link.
As part of this course, there is a Google Doc study guide that the students should be filling out (and sharing with their instructor).

I was wondering about which is the most viable solution:
1.  When joining the course, use Google (Drive API or Apps Script (?)) to create an instance of the file (presumably by either copying an existing one or using a named template) with the appropriate sharing permissions (the learner and their instructor would both be able to see the files).  There would be no link to the file within the course, just instructions on how to access their already created file.
2.  Have some sort of handler so that I could insert a static link to this handler into the course; the handler would check if the user was logged into Google Drive, if the file existed it would open it, and if it didn't exist it would create it (using similar technique to above).  This would have the benefit of being able to insert the same link anywhere and the student could immediately go to their specific and personalized Google doc.

Any other suggestion or existing solution out there?

Much obliged,
David

Answer (score 0):

Both would need the same code that makes personalized copies. The only difference is the moment where you create them.

2 is better because it has less chances of failing since you create at most one copy at a time, and is also more practical to the user.

The 1 option needs to make bulk copies and those take time (drive api to make copy is slow) and script could timeout or reach some quota.

going with 1, one way is to have a single webapp published as owner which receives the drive file ID as a url parameter. on start, the app figures if the copy has already been done (by finding the file by title or by using script or user properties).

if the file isnt created yet, create a copy and share it with the user. then display a link to the file in the webapp. note that the script wont be able to open the file automatically, thus you need to show it as an anchor for the user to click.

to clarify, with this way the user always makes two clicks. once from your CMS and once in your webapp.

Comment: Thank you.   Can I ask what you mean by the script won't be able to open the doc automatically?  I'm assuming that I will have a click event by the user (to "open" their study guide).  Is that what you mean?